# Display MaterialUI LineProgress in React app downloading file

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

Trying to integrate download file [LineProgress](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/linear-progress) from [Material_UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/) into a React-Redux application.

**GamesComponent**:
- clicking download button triggers GamesAction

**GamesAction**:
- dipatches call to GamesApi 
- returns a dispatch to the GamesReducer

```
export function downloadGame(file_url, targetPath, callback) {
  return (dispatch) =>
    GamesApi.downloadGame(file_url, targetPath, callback)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        return dispatch({
          type: GAMES_DOWNLOADGAME,
          progress: response
        })
      })
}
```

**GamesApi**:
- downloads the file
- returns a Promise to GamesAction with the **progress**

```
static downloadGame(file_url, targetPath, callback) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var req = request({
      method: 'GET',
      uri: file_url
    });

    var out = fs.createWriteStream(targetPath);
    req.pipe(out);

    req.on('response', function (data) {
      total_bytes = parseInt(data.headers['content-length']);
    });

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
      received_bytes += chunk.length;

      let progress = (received_bytes * 100) / total_bytes;
      console.log(progress)
      return resolve(progress)
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
      console.log("File succesfully downloaded");
    });
  })
}
```

**GamesReducer**:
- stores the progress to the store, so the component can grab it and display it on page.

```
case GAMES_DOWNLOADGAME:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    progress: action.progress
  })
```

**Result**:
Console.log displays the correct data when downloading.
But **how could i integrate it to the Component?**

What else could i use instead of a promise in order to be able to send something like download progress? 1%, 2%, ....100%

That sounds pretty horrible, but i can't think of a better way. If anyone knows a different way, or any working way, please point me to that direction. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you resolving in the data event?

Comment: If I understood right what is your approach, your promise resolves the first chunk the server responds. Instead of resolving in the data event you could probably trigger and action to update the state progress attribute. This attribute you can bind to the UI with react-redux, normally.

Comment: @AndreyLuiz `Why are you resolving in the data event?` How else could i do it? How else could i send the progress from the api to the action, reducer, store, view?

Comment: Like I said, instead of resolving the promise in the data event, you could dispatch an action to update a property in your state to track uploaded data. Only when the end event is triggered you should resolve, because you indeed have the upload finished. Try to architect this way.